# Selenium WebDriver Nunit works on debug and error on run (fail at popup window)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# Selenium WebDriver and Nunit.My test case work fine when execute test case in debug mode.However when I execute test case in run mode.Test case get fails with message

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ctl00_btnApprove"}

This issue is only when test case try to open POPup window.
As suggested by Volodymyr Bilyachat I created log of driver.PageSource.
In Debug Mode PageSource have control "ctl00_btnApprove".
However in run Mode PageSource doesn't have control "ctl00_btnApprove".

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to access an element before the page has finished loading.  You'll need to provide more code.

Comment: Its definitely issue with ajax or any other timeout

Comment: I have added explicit timeout but still I am getting same issue. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                IWebElement category = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                {
                    return d.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_btnApprove"));
                });

Comment: try to log when you write browser.PageSource property and see if this element is there

Comment: Thanks I will log browser.PageSource and verify same.

Comment: @Prakash try to avoid timeouts as much as possible. timeouts its abstract thing, because if you set timeout for 1second later could be it will use 2 seconds once a while and so on

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr Bilyachat , I created log of driver.PageSource.
In Debug Mode PageSource have control "ctl00_btnApprove".
However in run Mode PageSource doesn't have control "ctl00_btnApprove". This issue is only when test case try to open POPup window.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting using expected conditions

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var elem = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ctl00_btnApprove"));
```